how Get the user path when user upload an img instead of getting the img name in Node.js & express.js
When trying to get the user path to display the image on another page
I write this code
     var bi = __dirname+req.body.image;

but it gives me this my directory
C:\\Users\\SulaimanAbdulRazzaqY\\Desktop\\Full Stack Development\\5.0 Capstone_Projectme.jpg

how can I get the user path to Display img
I tried to save it in DB and get it by ejs
        <% for (let item of ItemLists) {%>
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src="<%= item.book_img %>" id="image" class="card-img-top">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><%= item.book_title%></h5>
                  <p class="card-text"><%= item.book_description %>.</p>
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                </div>
              </div>
        <% } %>

It gives me this
C:\\Users\\SulaimanAbdulRazzaqY\\Desktop\\Full Stack Development\\5.0 Capstone_Projectme.jpg

but its not in this directory it's in the picture folder. Because of that I want to get the the full path to display the image

I'm confused if you want to get C:\\Users\\SulaimanAbdulRazzaqY\\Pictures\\5.0 Capstone_Projectme.jpg or C:\\Users\\SulaimanAbdulRazzaqY\\Desktop\\Full Stack Development\\Pictures\\5.0 Capstone_Projectme.jpg but either way it doesn't make sense what you do. For the windows pictures folder, you don't need __dirname, but the path to the pictures folder. On the other hand, for a pictures folder  in the project, you need to say __dirname + "/path/to/pictures/folder" + req.body.image

thanks man I don't need you and I don't need StackOverflow.
Chat GPT is my hero

Well, as long you understand what the AI shows you, I guess that's fine.
